# Sort some list elements in certain positions, leaving other positions unchanged

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of elements, with associated sorting keys

```py
data = [
 {'data': 0},
 {'key': 'foo', 'data': 1},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 2},
 {'data': 3},
 {'key': 'foo', 'data': 4},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 5},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 6},
 {'data': 7}
]
```

Some elements has sorting `key`, some does not. I have an external table with sorting for some  keys:

```py
ORDER = ['bar', 'foo', 'baz']
```

Expected result:

```py
[
 {'data': 0},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 2},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 5},
 {'data': 3},
 {'key': 'bar', 'data': 6},
 {'key': 'foo', 'data': 1},
 {'key': 'foo', 'data': 4},
 {'data': 7}
]
```

I need to sort the array in the way that only elements with key are moved, and elements with the same key are not moved. (Basically, I have a partial order for elements with requirements to not to swap elements if key comparison does not require so). As far as I can see, existing `list.sort`/`sorted` (in Python) does not support this type of ordering.

I strongly suspect this problem was solved many times, but I can't find a proper name to search.

How this type of sorting is called?

Comment: does the order of  ```{'key': 'foo', 'data': 4},
 {'key': 'foo', 'data': 1}``` matter?

Comment: You need a stable sort like mergesort. The comparison function can be used as per need.

Comment: Ooop, it's a bug in my example, order for non-sorted elements should be preserved.

Comment: You say "only elements with key are moved" but then you expect `{'data': 3}` to get moved? What's up with that?

Comment: You right. It's a typo in example. It's hard to sort it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an iterator of sorted records:

```
it1 = iter(sorted((d for d in data if 'key' in d), 
                  key=lambda d_: ORDER.index(d_['key'])))
```

Next, write a list comprehension to selectively overwrite records with "key", leaving others unchanged.

```
res = [d if 'key' not in d else next(it1) for d in data]
print (res)
# [{'data': 0},
#  {'key': 'bar', 'data': 2},
#  {'key': 'bar', 'data': 5},
#  {'data': 3},
#  {'key': 'bar', 'data': 6},
#  {'key': 'foo', 'data': 1},
#  {'key': 'foo', 'data': 4},
#  {'data': 7}]
```

Some points:

- it might be worth converting `ORDER` into a dictionary mapping keys to positions, so the lookup is constant time. That should bring down the complexity of the sorting step.
- `sorted` returns a list, which is then converted to an iterator, so the intermediate list cannot be avoided.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I still don't know how this sorting is called, though. Insofar it's cs95-sort, I guess.

Comment: I don't know the name either but it's not an uncommon question. Selective sort? Partial sort? Virtual sublist sort? Who knows!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in O(n) time, if you have few keys, using something like a [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) for example:

```
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

# create buckets
buckets, no_key = defaultdict(list), {}
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if 'key' in d:
        buckets[d['key']].append(d)
    else:
        no_key[i] = d

# create one sorted list for elements with keys, basically iterate over the buckets in ORDER
chained = list(chain.from_iterable([buckets[key] for key in ORDER]))[::-1]

# combine the two iterables, chained and no_key into the final result
final = [no_key.pop(i) if i in no_key else chained.pop() for i in range(len(data))]
pprint.pprint(final)
```

**Output**

```
[{'data': 0},
 {'data': 2, 'key': 'bar'},
 {'data': 5, 'key': 'bar'},
 {'data': 3},
 {'data': 6, 'key': 'bar'},
 {'data': 1, 'key': 'foo'},
 {'data': 4, 'key': 'foo'},
 {'data': 7}]
```